# Hadoop node is not active

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have 1 x master node and 1 x slave node setup.

My issue is when running the map reduce processing. The slave node doesn't seem working. Anyone can provide help on how to check, to change and ensure the slave is working?

The config files info can be found on the URL below too
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULEe6k2zYnfQDQUQIbz_xR29WgT1DJhB/view

Here are my observation

1) When i check the CPU resources utilization, The slaves doesn't seem working and CPU resources at 0% when running the map reduce job while the master at 44% CPU resources. refer to the attachment.

2) When i run the dfs report it show it has 2 live nodes but on the cluster web it show only 1. Refer to the attachment and below.
[image]
3) The total processing time of map reduce is same with or without the slave

```
-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (2):

Name: 192.168.249.128:9866 (node-master)
Hostname: localhost
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 20587741184 (19.17 GB)
DFS Used: 174785723 (166.69 MB)
Non DFS Used: 60308293 (57.51 MB)
DFS Remaining: 20352647168 (18.95 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.85%
DFS Remaining%: 98.86%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Oct 23 11:17:39 PDT 2018
Last Block Report: Tue Oct 23 11:07:32 PDT 2018
Num of Blocks: 93


Name: 192.168.249.129:9866 (node1)
Hostname: localhost
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 20587741184 (19.17 GB)
DFS Used: 85743 (83.73 KB)
Non DFS Used: 33775889 (32.21 MB)
DFS Remaining: 20553879552 (19.14 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 99.84%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Oct 23 11:17:38 PDT 2018
Last Block Report: Tue Oct 23 11:03:59 PDT 2018
Num of Blocks: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're showing datanodes with dfsreport, not nodemanagers that actually are processing the data. In the YARN UI, you will want to take note of the "Active Nodes" counter, which in your case is **1**. That would make sense if the master is a namenode and resource manager while the slave would be a datanode and nodemanager.

Other than that, if you have a non splittable file, for example a ZIP, or your file is less than the block size (by default 128 MB), then only one mapper will process that. Plus, it's not guaranteed that mappers (or reducers) will be distributed evenly over all available resources

Outside of a learning environment, though, 40 GB of storage and 8 GB of RAM would be better spent on multi threading rather than distributed computing (or a proper database; i.e parse files and load them into a queryable store). Or use Spark or Pig, which don't require Hadoop, but are much easier to work with than MapReduce

Comment: just checkout the comparison of pig and spark yet found hadoop is still the best for high scalability and huge data processing. 2ndly, organisation chosen hadoop and many already run in production. Just another question here, it that possible to force the mappers (or reducers) to run on 2 nodes? or selective nodes? Just want to check out the performance

Comment: Hadoop is not an alternative to either of those; HDFS stores the data, whereas Pig/Spark are better declarative alternatives to MapReduce and both can run locally or on YARN. And as mentioned, you need a splittable file that is larger than the block size to get more than one mapper to run. You also need more than one slave node